# Remove part of url to send to database

Tags: php, file

Im using this:

```
$field_value = $_POST[$field['name']];
```

to send the value of a field to the database. At the moment it sends the full url, i.e

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/img/filename.jpg
```

I want to change it so that it only filename.jpg stays, the rest is removed.

Comment: `echo basename("http://www.mywebsite.com/img/filename.jpg");` would probably suffice.

Comment: I see an SQL Injection hole.

Answer (score 2):

```
str_replace($field_value, "http://www.mywebsite.com/img/", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can split link string from every "/" and take the last one:

```
substr(strrchr($field_value, '/'), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might don't care about domain, and just look basename, like:

```
<?php
var_export([
    basename('http://www.mywebsite.com/img/filename.jpg'),
    basename('http://www.my-prod-website.com/css/filename.jpg'),
    basename('http://www.my-dev-website.com/css/filename.jpg'),
]);
```

Result:

```
array (
  0 => 'filename.jpg',
  1 => 'filename.jpg',
  2 => 'filename.jpg',
)
```